firestore query an array
I'm currently working with Firestore and I'm aiming to create a 'withdrawMade' array with different statuses. Specifically, I'm looking to retrieve a list of data where the status is set to 'pending'. Could someone kindly guide me on how to achieve this?

  async function fetchRequests() {
        try {
            const paymentProfileRef = collection(db, "paymentProfile");
            const q = query(
                paymentProfileRef,
                where("withdrawMade.status", "==", "pending"),
                orderBy("withdrawMade.date", "asc")
            );
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

            const requestData = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const data = doc.data();
                data.withdrawMade.forEach((withdrawal) => {
                    // Include document ID along with user data
                    requestData.push({ id: doc.id, ...withdrawal });
                });
            });

            setRequestsList(requestData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching requests:", error);
        }
    }


Firestore can only query for full matches of items in an array (with its array-contains operator). There is no way to find a partial match in an array. The workaround is to add additional array fields with just the properties of the array items you want to filter on (i.e. withdrawMadeStatuses: ["pending", "paid"] and withdrawMadeDates: [date1, date2]) and then query on one of those with array-contains.
